# simplify bash parameter verification with regexp

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script and I am validating the input parameters that the user provides this way:

```
if [[ ($# -lt 1 || $# -gt 5)
    || ($# -eq 1 && ! "$1" =~ ^(help|clean)$)
    || ($# -gt 1 &&
        (! "$1" =~ ^(build|clean|install|deploy|remove)$
            || ! "$2" =~ ^(|build|clean|install|deploy|remove)$
            || ! "$3" =~ ^(|build|clean|install|deploy|remove)$
            || ! "$4" =~ ^(|build|clean|install|deploy|remove)$
            || ! "$5" =~ ^(|build|clean|install|deploy|remove)$)) ]]; then
      show_help
      exit 1
fi
```

**The validation rule is the following:**

- running without parameters is not allowed
- maximum 5 parameters are allowed
- if only one param is provided then it must be `help` or `clean`.
- if more than one parameters are provided then they must be one of the following: `build`, `clean`, `install`, `deploy`, `remove`

Is there any way to simplify the last 5 conditions and avoid the repetitions?

Comment: @Jens Without proper description of what the code does, it's off-topic everywhere.

Comment: For your $2, $3, $4, $5 you could use `shift` to loop through your arguments.  But if it works for your need, move on and complete your work.

Comment: I accept params or nothing. The empty string is not acceptable. E.g. `./tool.sh build build` is valid but `./tool.sh build ""` not valid. Anyway, my question is more about avoiding repetition in the `if` condition.